# How to update DNSSEC using GoDaddy's API?

Tags: godaddy-api

Reading through GoDaddy's domains endpoint documentation ( [https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) ) am trying to use GoDaddy's API to update DNSSEC records (DS records to be more precise). Very few examples (found none actually) are out there showing how to actually do that.

The above documentation does seem to mention a "**model**" called **DomainDnssec** (same URL as above) which does refer to values and their types that need to be either POST'ed or GET'ed using one of the API URLs but it's not clear to me which one. What is "**model**" in that context anyway (literally just a description of data types that have to be posted or received using particular API endpoints? this is not clear to me either and documentation is silent about that)?

As much as I do not have an issue with using API in general (all set up and working, together with finding out infamous customerId which most folks confuse with shopperId), I'm having a hard time finding which API call allows interacting with DNSSEC on GoDaddy's API.

I did not try much yet as none of the actions (API calls) within the API domain namespace documentation seems related particularly to DNSSEC.

===an update

It seems that in the Action model (https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#/), there is a reference to API calls that do not seem to be documented:

- DNSSEC_CREATE - Request to create DNSSEC record for the domain via PATCH /v2/customers/{customerId}/domains/{domain}/dnssecRecords
- DNSSEC_DELETE - Request to delete DNSSEC record for the domain via DELETE /v2/customers/{customerId}/domains/{domain}/dnssecRecords

Not sure why this call is not explicitly documented among other v2 API calls. An overlook? Still not sure how to build API calls allowing to update DNSSEC records.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they have not yet implemented the call.

> Error: 501, {"code":"NOT_IMPLEMENTED","message":"operation PATCH.v2_customers__domains__dnssecRecords has not yet been implemented"}